# Module returning asynchronously initialited object

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, initialization, return-value

I'm having this "design" problem that's driving me crazy.

My goal is having a decoupled RabbitMQ client. It has to be able to init it's connection and "return" a created channel so my publishing module can use it.

Code looks like this (i know that is not the better code but i expect it serves for this explanation).

```
var createConnection = (function() {

var channel;
var connect = function(){
        // amqp connect
        // error handling
        createChannel();
    });
}

var createChannel = function(){
    //amqpConn.createConfirmChannel...
}

//pseudo
return{
    getChannel : function(){
        if(!initiated)
            connect();
        return channel;
    }
}
})();

module.exports = createConnection;
```

Now, important things:

1- I know this ain't gonna work and i know why, its a simplification. 
2- I'm aware that i can accomplish my goals by using async or promises.
3- Maybe has no sense decoupling a rabbit client but is for understanding purposes

That said, my questions:

1- Is there any way i can accomplish this without using other modules?
2- if so, can be accomplished in a fancy and stylish way?
3- Is there any fancy solution that allows 3rd party code executing a simple "publish(exchange, channel, msg)" been sure that connection has been established?

I feel able to work with JS but sometimes you just need do things one way only to know that you can but this is giving me some headache.

Truly thanks and i hope the question was understood :)

Comment: Maybe by using a promise?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer :)

As I stated:

2- I'm aware that i can accomplish my goals by using async or promises.

So, if it's impossible doing without promises it's fine by me. I need to know if there's a good way to do it without other modules.

Regards.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question directly, but instead of exporting something asynchronous, I've found it's easier to export a function which will create the connection for you once it's called, but explicitly instead of lazily. Then you can setup a bootstrap section of your application which will instantiate the connection and provide it to the other modules when it's ready. The way you have it set up, if two modules call `getChannel` simultaneously, they're probably both going to call `connect` (depending on where you put that `initiated = true` switch).

Answer (score 0):

One way I've found to handle this is to wrap your asynchronous object in an object that is aware of the asynchronous state of your object and presents the same API regardless of whether or not the asynchronous object has finished initializing.

For example, you could wrap your `channel` object in another object that presents the same methods but internally checks if the actual `channel` object is initialized. If it is, use it as normal. If it isn't, wait for it to be initialized and use it as normal. The user of the wrapper object wouldn't need to know if the channel is actually initialized. The main drawback of this is every wrapper method that needs to access `channel` must be asynchronous even if the method it's accessing on `channel` is synchronous.

Example:

```
function initializeChannel() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // create, initialize, and resolve channel
  });
}

module.exports = { // wrapper
  channelPromise: initializeChannel(),
  foo(a) {
    return this.channelPromise.then((channel) => channel.foo(a));
  }
};
```